# Export-Csv Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am trying to fetch the AD group members information through power shell. But I am getting the messages as

> Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Path = Get-Location

$GroupName = Read-Host "Type the Group Name to check the members in it`t "

foreach ($group in $GroupName) {
    $users = @{}

    Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Property Name, DisplayName | ForEach-Object {
        $users[$_.DistinguishedName] = $_
    }

    $MemberCount = (Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member | Select-Object -Expand Member).Count

    Write-Host "`t Total Number of Users/Groups added on this Group : $MemberCount" -BackgroundColor DarkCyan

    $Info = Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member |
            Select-Object -Expand Member |
            ForEach-Object { $users[$_] }

    $Info | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force $Path\new.csv
```

Comment: Most likely `$Info` contains emtpy/null values. My guess would be that some of your group members are orphaned (account was deleted w/o removing group membership) or external references or someting like that. Change `ForEach-Object { $users[$_] }` to something like `ForEach-Object { if ($users.ContainsKey($_)) {$users[$_]} else {Write-Host "Unknown DN: ${_}"} }`.

Comment: Thanks Angar - edited the way u suggested. its worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `$Info` contains empty/null values. The most likely reason for their presence is that the group has members that aren't returned by `Get-ADUser`.

You can avoid the issue by checking for the presence of the key in the `$users` hashtable:

```
$Info = Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member |
        Select-Object -Expand Member |
        ForEach-Object { if ($users.ContainsKey($_) {$users[$_]} }
```

If you want to further investigate the missing distinguished names you could collect them like this:

```
$missing = Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member |
           Select-Object -Expand Member |
           ForEach-Object { if (-not $users.ContainsKey($_) {$_} }
```

Comment: please check below